# How to learn to understand the Newfoundland accent?

Tags: accent

Recently I watched a video with Newfoundland accent:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXLmCJG9USw

Apparently it is English :) However my colleagues and I find it literally impossible to understand except maybe a few separate words. As native speakers do you understand it? If it not to much trouble maybe you could write a transcription for us?

Comment: I was utterly lost, apart from a few instances of swear words. I could provide a transcript of just the bits I understood, but it might not be appropriate :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service.

Comment: It's deepest, darkest Newfie accents--they're trying to make it incomprehensible to everyone except people who live there. I wouldn't be surprised if the beginning stuff was just about nonsense (what you would say to attract a cat or a dog), then it switches into, "hey, where ya from".

Comment: Wikipedia has an informative article on [Newfoundland English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_English).

Comment: They're speaking *extremely* rapidly. If it were slowed down, you would understand quite a lot of what is being said.